# Python Dictionary.values()

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dict a

```
a = [{'shape': 'square', 'size': 'large', 'color': 'blue'}]
```

with values

```
a.values() = ['square','large','blue']
```

I want to compare it to my list which is

```
myList = ['square', 'large', 'blue']
```

I want to compare these two objects so that they equate to True when I compare them, such as:

```
if list(a.values().values()) == myList:
    return True
```

So I think I would need to grab the values of the a.values(), but what would be the best way to go about doing this?

Let me know if more details are required. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean `a.values()` is a list containing a single `dict`? That's... strange. I'm assuming you mean the `dict` in that `list` is defined as given, but if I'm wrong, you'll just need to tweak my answer to drill down into your `a` appropriately.

Comment: Let me edit my question to be more clear. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `all()` to iterate over each value of the dictionary contained in `new_list` and check if that value exists in `myList`:

```
new_list = a.values() #new_list contais[{'shape': 'square', 'size': 'large', 'color': 'blue'}]
myList = ['square', 'large', 'blue']
if all(i in myList for i in new_list[0].values()):
    pass
```

Comment: @shpakz glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

`dict`s don't have defined order, for either keys or values (more precisely, keys have arbitrary order, and the values follow the same ordering as the keys). If you want to check if the `values` match an expected set of values, you'll need to use set operations to do it properly, or impose an ordering on your values.

If duplicates are not a possibility, you can just convert both the values and the set of values to test to `set` and compare:

```
set(a.values()) == set(myList)
```

If duplicates are a possibility, you'll want to either sort and compare (`O(n log n)`) or use a `collections.Counter` (requires import, but `O(n)`):

```
sorted(a.values()) == sorted(myList)
```

or

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(a.values()) == Counter(myList)
```

Comment: I tried to make my question more clear but I'm not sure if I've actually made it more confusing. Basically, I need to get a list of the second part of my a.values() to compare to myList, probably using a set operation.